# Printing from SQL in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to print text I have placed into a MySql database. I have been able to insert into the database, but I don't know what to put to take out the value/text

```
<?php

  require("../includes/config.php");

  if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
  {
  $query = mysqlquery("INSERT INTO posts (post_content) VALUES (?)", $_POST["comment"]);

  $comment = mysqlquery("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE post_content = ?", $_POST["comment"]);

  echo('<div class="container">');
  echo('<ul class="media-list forum" style = "padding: 20px 0px 20px 0px;">');
  echo('<li class="media well">');
  echo('<div class="pull-left user-info" href="#">');
  echo('<img src="img/merylface.png" width="64" alt="Everyone is Meryl">');
  echo('<div>');
  echo('<strong>Anonymous</strong>');
  echo('</div>');
  echo('</div>');
  echo('<div class="media-body">');
  echo($comment);
  echo('</div>');
  echo('</li>');
  echo('</ul>');
  echo('</div>');
  }
?>
```

Comment: What is mysqlquery? Is that a typo or a custom function?

Comment: It's really not good enough to fail to edit code that you know to be wrong. It just wastes time.

Answer (score 0):

Use

`mysql_query` and better is `mysqli_query` as [here](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_query.asp)

instead of `mysqlquery`

Comment: Thanks, I changed that as soon as I posted but the issue is echo($comment).  What am I echoing to post just the text passed through POST?

Comment: Please edit your post with lable EDIT and add latest code with any custom function involved if there.

Answer (score 0):

use it like this

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($comment)) {
  print_r($row);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your "mysqlquery" there is a custom function, included somewhere that will return the data, it will probably be in $comment['post_content'].